# Windows Store not working

Tags: windows-10, modern-ui, windows-store-app

I performed a clean install of Windows 10 and now the Store does not load. The window appears but it just remains blank and sometimes shows the following message: [image]

I have tried running `wreset.exe` and also removing and reinstalling the Store app using PowerShell(steps followed from [here](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-restore-windows-store-in-windows-10-after-removing-it-with-powershell/)) but haven't got any positive results.

How do I fix the Store?

**EDIT:** On running

```
Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register $Env:SystemRoot\WinS
tore\AppxManifest.XML
```

I get this error:

```
Add-AppxPackage : Cannot find path 'C:\WINDOWS\WinStore\AppxManifest.XML' because it does
    not exist.
    At line:1 char:1
    + Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register $Env:SystemRoot\Win ...
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\WINDOWS\WinStore\AppxManifest.XML:String)
       [Add-AppxPackage], ItemNotFoundException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.Ad
       dAppxPackageCommand

I don't know if something is wrong here.
```

Comment: 0x80072EE2 = ERROR_INTERNET_TIMEOUT disable any 3rd party AV suites and try again

Comment: @magicandre1981 I don't have any 3rd party AV's installed.

Answer (score 0):

I think this ggenerally happens when Windows Servers are getting overloaded. I have faced similar problem & these are temporary one. Restart your PC, connect it to internet & run Windows Update in settings. Wait for 15 to 20 minutes & it will go away. Check
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/windows-update-error-80072ee2#1TC=windows-7